# Create_Analytics in RTextTools

Tags: r, precision, text-mining, document-classification, confusion-matrix

I trying to classify Text documents into number of categories.
My below code works fine

```
matrix[[i]] <- create_matrix(trainingdata[[i]][,1], language="english",removeNumbers=FALSE,stemWords=FALSE,weighting=weightTf,minWordLength=3)                              
container[[i]] <- create_container(matrix[[i]],trainingdata[[i]][,2],trainSize=1:50,testSize=51:100) ,
models[[i]] <- train_models(container[[i]], algorithms=c("MAXENT","SVM"))
results[[i]] = classify_models(container[[i]],models[[i]])
```

When i try to the below code to get Precision, recall, accuracy values:

```
analytic[[i]]  <- create_analytics(container[[i]], results[[i]])
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = c(NA_real_, NA_real_ : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
```

My `Categories` are in `text` format.
If i convert those `categories` into `Numeric` - the above code works fine.

Is there a work around to keep the categories in `text` format and get Precision, recall, accuracy values.

My objective is to get Precision, recall, accuracy values and Confusion matrix for multi-class classifier.
Is there any other package to get the above values for Multi- Class Text classifier (one vs. all )

Comment: can you try if `factor(Categories)` works for you

Comment: Is there any work around , to do this

Comment: I have the same error.  in RTextTools::create_analytics  there is a a local function called create_Topic summary, which  has  testing_codes <- as.numeric(as.vector(container@testing_codes))  This causes NA to fill testing_codes.  Still looking into it.

Comment: Ok I got it to work.  I had to 1. convert it to a factor.  Then convert the factor to a number.  I guess it is like "Class 1" -> 1, "Class 2"->2.  If you look at the example in [RTextTools: A supervised Learning Package for Text Classification](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2013-1/collingwood-jurka-boydstun-etal.pdf), the example uses USCongress$major as a class label.  That happened to be an integer.

Answer (score 8):

As user3294343 commented, it worked for me converting my class field to a factor, and then to numeric, as follows:

```
doc_matrix <- create_matrix(dataset.arff$text, language="english", removeNumbers=TRUE, stemWords=TRUE, removeSparseTerms=.998)
container <- create_container(doc_matrix, as.numeric(factor(dataset.arff$"@@class@@")), trainSize=1:1500, testSize=1501:1999, virgin=FALSE)
```

That solved the error for me.

Answer (score 0):

Above mentioned trick worked for me, **convert to factors**

```
matrix <- create_matrix(combinedDF["error"], language="english", 
                    removeNumbers=TRUE, stemWords=FALSE, weighting=tm::weightTfIdf)
len <- dim(combinedDF)[1]
container <- create_container(matrix,as.numeric(factor(combinedDF$class)),trainSize=1:len, testSize=1:len, 
                          virgin=TRUE)
maxent_model <- train_model(container,"MAXENT")
maxent_results <- classify_model(container,maxent_model)
analytics <- create_analytics(container, maxent_results, b=1)
```

Comment: can you please tell what is the difference between your answer and the answer from dsg?